# Why did Mordecai save Achashverosh?

Tags: tanach, megillat-esther

It is known that Achashverosh was an evil king and encouraged Haman to kill the Jews in exchange for making money. Moreover,he made a feast for the Jews with the temple vessels. If so, why did Mordechai save Achashverosh and pass on the information that Bigthan and Teresh wanted to kill him? After all, this could have been an excellent opportunity to change the monarchy and perhaps get a king who is good for the Jews? And perhaps because Achashverosh remained on his throne, every issue of the decree of Haman was dragged out and the Jews needed a miracle, and in the way that Bigthan and Teresh were successful in their way, could all the decrees of King Achashverosh have been avoided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is addressed in Rabbi Yosef Deutsch's *[Let My Nation Live](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578197828.html)* p.47:

> Mordechai could, of course, have pretended he had never heard the plotters, allowing them to carry out their plot and kill Achashverosh. Esther would then have been free to return home. But he decided to thwart the plot. If the plotters succeeded, he reasoned, the Jewish chief advisor would be blamed for the lax security. If it were discovered that Esther was Jewish, there would be suspicions of a conspiracy between her and Mordechai. In either case, a chillul Hashem, a desecration of the Name, would result. On the other hand, by speaking up he would make a kiddush Hashem, sanctifying the Name. He would bring honor to the Jewish people and gain royal favor for the reconstruction of the Beis Hamikdash.<sup>1</sup> Furthermore, he believed in his heart that Hashem had let him learn about the plot so that he should expose it.

---

> <sup>1</sup> [Yalkut Shimoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.1053.29-32?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); Midrash Panim Acheirim; Me'am Loez.